# Rails - how do I make sure a partial has been rendered in a js.erb

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, render

I am trying to bind a JS function to a text field (input of type "text"). Using JQuery 2.0.2 & Rails 3.1 I do this in a `.js.coffee` file located in `assets/javascripts`:

```
window.test_questions = {}
window.test_questions.bind_input = ->
  $('#question_content').on 'input', ->
    // do something
```

Then in a `.js.erb` located in the `views\TheRightController` folder I run:

```
$('#new_question').html('<%= escape_javascript(render("new_question_form")) %>');   
test_questions.bind_input();
```

`#question_content` does not exist on the page until the partial is rendered. I am worried that `bind_input()` will run before the render is complete, not find `#question_content` and  bind nothing to it.

I am not 100% this is a problem (my code is working at the moment), but I am worried that if I use it elsewhere with a "heavier" render it will break.

Am I worried in vain?
Is there any way to make sure the render is complete without errors, and only then execute the next line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two steps here.

First the Ruby script is executed and turned into a plain html/javascript file. This is done by the server before serving the page to the client. At this step, all your `<%= %>` will be executed. So there is no need to worry about the JavaScript being executed before the Rails `render`.

Then the client receives the page and starts rendering it and executing the javascript. If you call `$('#new_question').html` before `bind_input`, again no need to worry, it will be executed synchronously and your selector `#question_content` will work. Another selector may break however, if you're running `$('#new_question')` before the DOM is fully loaded. To prevent that, use JQuery's [`$(document).ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Comment: A quick followup, does the `$(document).ready()` trigger again after an asynchronous ajax call that renders new partials? I thought it only runs when the page first loads.

Comment: No, the handler passed to `ready()` will be executed only once in normal situations (e.g you don't have multiple jquery included, or other weird things). The best way to handle what happens after an ajax call is resolved is to used `.done()` http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/